# UIPanGestureRecognizer top level view not getting events, subviews consuming them

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

Using UIPanGestureRecognizer & UITapGestureRecognizer on top-level UIView.

The setup in Interface Builder:

- **ViewController** (our main view controller)
- **UIView** (our main view and wired to our UIViewController
- Our core **UIView** has a subview called a “**Block**” which is simply a **UIView**.
- The **Block** view has 4 **subviews** (children) each being an instance of a **UIButton**.
- The **UIButton** has its **Touch Up Inside** event wired to the the UIViewController.
- The UIView (our main top-level UIView) has a **UIPanGestureRecognizer** and a **UITapGestureRecognizer**

Here is the scenario we are trying to accomplish (a.k.a.The behavior):

1. A user taps a button (a cell).
2. The button will change its stated from “normal” to “selected”. (This works fine and the code is simple)
3. With a selected item, a user can place their finger anywhere on the screen an move it up or down

The issue:

- Need to know when panning stops.
- The top UIView does not receive a gesture stated of ended.
- The UIView does not receive a touchesEnded event.

How do you know when the user has lifted their finger? Suppose I start the panning when my finger is over a UIButton, while panning occurs, the UIButton eats the touches begin and end events. Therefore, you have no way of knowing when the user stopped moving their finger across the iPhone/iPad glass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in your view controller.
Then set the delegate on your gesture recognizers to self and implement the following method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
 return YES;
}
```

Your target method should look like this:

```
-(void)gestureRegognized:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
 if ([gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
 {
   //check its state
   if(gestureRecognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
   {
     // add your code here
   }
   else if(gestureRecognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
   {
     // pan gesture ended code goes here
   }

 }
 else if([gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
 {
   if(gestureRecognizer.state!=UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
   {   
     // tap gesture detected
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It appears my issue was that I added a UIPanGestureRecognizer in Interface builder, setup the delegate and the action. In the IBAction, I set my method as - (IBAction)onPanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer; This was failing. When I simply hard-coded the creation of the gesture recognizers (as suggested above) everything now works.

Comment: Happy I could help. If happy with my answer please accept it.